# Can't Set Properties for Azure Blob with Azure SDK for Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to set properties of the files inside my blob location but somehow it's not persistent.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings
connect_str="connectionString"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("$web")

# List files in blob folder
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs_list:
    print(blob.content_settings.content_type) # application/octet-stream
    blob.content_settings.content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    print(blob.content_settings.content_type)
```

Output:

> application/octet-stream

> text/html; charset=utf-8

But when I again try to run:

```
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs_list:
    print(blob.content_settings.content_type)
```

I still get `application/octet-stream` which I am not able to understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we do `blob.content_settings.content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"` this only changes the variable on your local machine (*no requests are being sent to change this value*).
It is essentially like setting any other variable within your Python program.

If you want this value to persist on your storage account you must send out a request. In order to change this value you'd have to do something like:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings
connect_str="connectionString"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("$web")

# List files in blob folder
blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs_list:
    print(blob.content_settings.content_type) # application/octet-stream
    blob.set_http_headers(
    content_settings=ContentSettings(
        content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed a local variable, you need an explicit call to change the property on Azure itself. You need to build a blobclient and to call `set_http_headers`. From inside your loop:

```
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
    blob_client.set_http_headers(
        content_settings=ContentSettings(
            content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"
        )
    )
```

Feel free to open an issue in the Azure SDK for Python if you feel this sample should be easier to find: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I work at MS in the Python SDK team)

Comment: I feel it confusing as BlobService, BlobContainer, and BlobClient Classes. Something simple from SDK would be helpful.